# How to get continuous surface from collection of data points?

Tags: data-visualization

I have a collection of datapoints in three dimensions x,y,z.
I'd like to be able to visualize the data as a smooth surface.

Stated another way:
Given those points, I'd like to be able to determine z for any arbitrary x and y such that the surface is smooth and continuous.

Tools available are anything that I can get my hands on for free.  Bias is for Processing, Python, or php.

Answer (score 3):

There is [scipy.interpolation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) for Python.

(This might be more of a question for stackoverflow or math.stackexchange.)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like @bayer's answer will work well for you. For someone using R, the `akima`, `fields`, and `tgp` packages among others, would do the job, depending on the type of interpolation you want.